# How to trim down unwanted text / characters from query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for the best way to exclude unwanted text from the results of the following query:

**QUERY:**

```
select message_
from jbpm_comment
order by time_ desc
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]
I've blacked out the url for security reasons. The highlighted text, ***"This is another test. I will accept!"*** is what I want to return. I need to figure out a way to drop everything else from the field:

**Need to drop:**

- **Before the text I need to keep:** 2015 Test Plan^|^^|^g9xg3^|^read^|^^|^2015 Test Plan - HR Approval has been accepted^|^
- **Following the text I need to keep:** html a href="https://URL_REMOVED_> Click here to view the details

I haven't been able to incorporate TRIM to work as needed, but I might be missing some functional steps. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're only showing fixed strings to remove. Do you have some kind of pattern/rule to identify the parts to keep and the parts to remove?

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response and thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, the strings will vary. They will follow a general pattern of "TEMPLATENAME^|^^|^USERID^|^READ/UNREAD^|^^|^ACCEPTED/INQUIRED^|^"THE TEXT I WANT TO KEEP <html>web url"    --    In other words, TEMPLATENAME will change, USERID will change, READ/UNREAD will fluctuate, ACCEPTED/INQUIRED will fluctuate with other status possibilities. The only static result appears to be the url link, starting with the <html> tag and ending with "Click here to view the details".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the pattern you describe, you can use regular expressions to remove the parts you don't want. You seem to have elements delimited by `^|^`, so you can remove anything enclosed by pairs of those with [the `regexp_replace()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm) and pattern `(\^\|\^.*\^\|\^)` (escaping the special characters), but you also want to get rid of the text before the first delimiter; you might be able to simplify this a bit but as a starting point and with a CTE to provide your two sample values:

```
with t as (
  select '2015 Test Plan^|^^|^g9xg3^|^read^|^^|^2015 Test Plan - HR Approval has been accepted^|^This is another test. I will accept!<html><a href="https://URL_REMOVED_> Click here to view the details' as text from dual
  union all select 'TemplateName^|^^|^USERID^|^read/unread^|^^|^Accepted or Inquired^|^THE TEXT I WANT TO KEEP <html>web url' as text from dual
)
select regexp_replace(text, '^.*(\^\|\^.*\^\|\^)')
from t;

KEEP                                                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is another test. I will accept!<html><a href="https://URL_REMOVED_> Click here to view the details  
THE TEXT I WANT TO KEEP <html>web url
```

Then the result of that can be fed to a second `regexp_replace` that removes anything starting with `<html>`:

```
with t as (
  select '2015 Test Plan^|^^|^g9xg3^|^read^|^^|^2015 Test Plan - HR Approval has been accepted^|^This is another test. I will accept!<html><a href="https://URL_REMOVED_> Click here to view the details' as text from dual
  union all select 'TemplateName^|^^|^USERID^|^read/unread^|^^|^Accepted or Inquired^|^THE TEXT I WANT TO KEEP <html>web url' as text from dual
)
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(text, '^.*(\^\|\^.*\^\|\^)'), '<html.*') as keep
from t;

KEEP                                    
----------------------------------------
This is another test. I will accept!     
THE TEXT I WANT TO KEEP
```

[Read more about Oracle's regular expression support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm).

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. One more question, and I can't believe I'm struggling with this after you laid it out above, but how might I remove everything in the string following "2015 Test Plan". I need to keep any text appearing before the first ^|^ in the string. In the example above, I would need to keep 2015 Test Plan, while dropping everything after ^|^^|^. I've tried to modify your code above as follows: `select regexp_replace(message_, '^|^^}^.*') from jbpm_comment`, but this is returning the entire field value, including unwanted characters.

Comment: @jdgaub - with `regexp_replace(text, '\^\|\^.*')`. Pattern matching is 'greedy' by default so it'll remove the longest matching string, which is everything from (including) the first delimiter. (in your version you aren't escaping the special symbols `^` and `|`; and not sure what `}` is doing in there *8-)

Comment: Yeah, that got it. So, the \ serves to break up the pattern string, forcing it to look at anything in between \    \ as a unique pattern? Am I understanding that correctly? Thanks again for your help. I always enjoying picking up new things from this site. Great resource.

Comment: @jdgaub - a `|` is usually an `or` operator and `^` denotes the start of the string (with `$` as the end). Using a backslash as an escape means they are treated as literal characters rather than operators. So the pattern is looking for `^|^` but with each character escaped - otherwise it doesn't match, or matches the wrong things. And then that's followed by any number of any character, from the `.*`. There are whole books about this stuff.. I still mostly still wing it and hack until it works *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (I'm not sure if it is static text you want to exclude, but if so, this may work for you)

`select replace('blabla I will accept blabla','I will accept','') from dual;`

Now only 'blabla blabla' left

Comment: I think you're dropping the wrong part, but it's hard to tell from the question. Nested replace calls would work to drop the two (different) 'blabla' bits though, if they are really fixed strings.